# Use build association between schemas

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have following schemas:

The first:

```
schema "countries_codes" do

    # Country code based on ISO-2
    field :iso,        :string
    field :name,       :string
    has_many :country, Country

    timestamps

  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do

    struct
    |> cast(params, [:iso, :name])
    |> validate_required([:iso, :name])
    |> validate_length(:iso, max: 2)

  end
```

the second:

```
schema "languages_codes" do

    # Language code based on ISO-2
    field :iso,        :string
    field :name,       :string
    has_many :country, Country

    timestamps

  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do

    struct
    |> cast(params, [:iso, :name])
    |> validate_required([:iso, :name])
    |> validate_length(:iso, max: 2)

  end
```

and the third:

```
schema "countries" do

    belongs_to :country_iso,  CountryCode
    belongs_to :language_iso, LanguageCode
    field :name,              :string

    timestamps

  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do

    struct
    |> cast(params, [:country_iso, :language_iso, :name])
    |> cast_assoc(:country_iso)
    |> validate_required([:country_iso, :language_iso, :name])

  end
```

as you can see on the third table, the first and second field belong to other schema.

When I run the `country` changeset function, I've got:

```
** (RuntimeError) casting assocs with cast/3 is not supported, use cast_assoc/3 instead
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:440: Ecto.Changeset.type!/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:415: Ecto.Changeset.process_param/8
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1247: Enum."-map_reduce/3-lists^mapfoldl/2-0-"/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:391: Ecto.Changeset.do_cast/7
    (busiket) web/models/country.ex:20: Busiket.Country.changeset/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1184: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    priv/repo/seeds.exs:48: (file)
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:71: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

My problem is, I do not know, how to write a changeset function for the schema `countries`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix error remove `:country_iso` and `:language_iso` form `cast/3` in schema `countries`.

Updated model `Country`:

```
defmodule MyApp.Country do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "countries" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :country_iso, MyApp.CountryCode
    belongs_to :language_iso, MyApp.LanguageCode

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :country_iso_id, :language_iso_id])
    |> cast_assoc(:country_iso)
    |> cast_assoc(:language_iso)
    |> unique_constraint(:country_iso_id)
    |> unique_constraint(:language_iso_id)
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

#### To create a new `Country` with new `CountryCode` and `LanguageCode`:

```
changeset = Country.changeset(%Country{}, %{
  name: "United Kingdom",
  country_iso: %{iso: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"},
  language_iso: %{iso: "en", name: "English"}
})
Repo.insert! changeset
```

#### Cannot insert changeset with duplicated associations

```
Repo.insert! %CountryCode{iso: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"}

changeset = Country.changeset(%Country{}, %{
  name: "United Kingdom",
  country_iso: %{iso: "GB", name: "United Kingdom 2"},
  language_iso: %{iso: "en", name: "English"}
})
{:error, changeset} = Repo.insert changeset
changeset.valid? # => false
changeset.changes[:country_iso].errors[:iso] # => {"has already been taken", []}
```

Need to add `unique_constraint(:iso)` into `CountryCode` changeset to make it work like that.

#### Insert changeset with existent association

```
country_iso = Repo.insert! %CountryCode{iso: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"}
changeset = Country.changeset(%Country{}, %{
  name: "United Kingdom",
  country_iso_id: country_iso.id,
  language_iso: %{iso: "en", name: "English"}
})
Repo.insert! changeset
country = Repo.one Country
country.country_iso_id == country_iso.id # => true
```

## Consider using column `iso` as primary key for tables `country_codes` and `language_codes`

See more - [Ecto Custom Primary Keys](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-custom-primary-keys)

### Migrations:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateCountryCode do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:countries_codes, primary_key: false) do
      add :iso, :string, size: 2, primary_key: true
      add :name, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateLanguageCode do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:languages_codes, primary_key: false) do
      add :iso, :string, size: 2, primary_key: true
      add :name, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateCountry do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:countries) do
      add :name, :string
      add :country_iso, references(:countries_codes, column: :iso, type: :string, on_delete: :nothing)
      add :language_iso, references(:languages_codes, column: :iso, type: :string, on_delete: :nothing)

      timestamps()
    end

    create unique_index(:countries, [:country_iso, :language_iso])
  end
end
```

### Models:

```
defmodule MyApp.CountryCode do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @primary_key {:iso, :string, []}
  schema "countries_codes" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :countries, MyApp.Country

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:iso, :name])
    |> validate_required([:iso, :name])
    |> validate_length(:iso, max: 2)
    |> unique_constraint(:iso)
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.LanguageCode do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @primary_key {:iso, :string, []}
  schema "languages_codes" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :countries, MyApp.Country

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:iso, :name])
    |> validate_required([:iso, :name])
    |> validate_length(:iso, max: 2)
    |> unique_constraint(:iso)
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.Country do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "countries" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :country_code, MyApp.CountryCode, foreign_key: :country_iso, references: :iso, type: :string
    belongs_to :language_code, MyApp.LanguageCode, foreign_key: :language_iso, references: :iso, type: :string

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :country_iso, :language_iso])
    |> validate_required([:name, :country_iso, :language_iso])
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:country_iso)
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:language_iso)
  end
end
```

Note [foreign_key_constraint/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#foreign_key_constraint/3) function - it adds validation error for `Country` changeset when nonexistent `country_iso` or `language_iso` is used.

I've also changed associations names to `country_code` and `language_code`

### Assume there are some country code and language code:

```
Repo.insert! %CountryCode{iso: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"}
Repo.insert! %LanguageCode{iso: "en", name: "English"}
```

### To create Country changeset and insert into database:

```
changeset = Country.changeset(%Country{}, %{name: "United Kingdom", country_iso: "GB", language_iso: "en"})
Repo.insert! changeset
```

Comment: I changed as you mentioned above and got following error: `a = Country.changeset(%Country{}, %{country_iso: "CH", language_iso: "EN", name: "Switzerland"})   
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{name: "Switzerland"},
 errors: [language_iso: {"is invalid", [type: :map]},
  country_iso: {"is invalid", [type: :map]}], data: #Busiket.Country<>,
 valid?: false>`

Comment: Can you add repo migrations into the question please? It seams that you have column `country_iso` of type `map` in database table `countries` instead of foreign key `country_iso_id` that should be used for `belongs_to` association by default.

Comment: Also please add model names (e.g. `defmodule MyApp.Country`). Thanks

Comment: here we go, i will find on github [link](https://github.com/kostonstyle/relation) .Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for your help. What confuse me is, when I would use with `assoc_cast`, why do I have to pass `country_iso: %{iso: "GB", name: "United Kingdom"}`, although the entry is already available on db.

Comment: Without your suggestion above, when I try to insert new country, I've got: `(Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

    * unique: countries_codes_iso_index

If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
call unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
constraint name. The changeset has not defined any constraint.`

Comment: It is caused because you are trying to insert a new `CountryCode` with the new `Country` but  `CountryCode` with such `iso` is already exist. So instead of creating new `CountryCode` need to use existent one. Also need to add [unique_constraint/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3) in `Country` model to convert exception to validation error.

Comment: I changed the changeset like this: `def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do

    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name])
    |> unique_constraint(:country_iso)
    |> unique_constraint(:language_iso)
    |> validate_required([:name])

  end`  Tried to use `iex(11)> changeset = Country.changeset(%Country{}, %{ name: "United Kingdosm", country_iso: "GB", language_iso: "EN"})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{name: "United Kingdosm"}, errors: [],
 data: #Relation.Country<>, valid?: true>` Nothing got inserted into country database.

Comment: To insert record into the database table use [Repo.insert/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert/2), changeset is only a set of changes that need to be inserted/updated. I've also added few examples into the answer. Thanks